# Cannot connect QPushButton

Tags: c++, qt

If I try to connect a button with a slot, the compiler told me:

```
QObject::connect: No such slot ClassA::..
```

ClassB inherit of ClassA. In ClassB I create a button and I will connecting it to a function in ClassB.

```
connect(btn, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(helloWorld()));
```

The reason is, `this` is mean ClassA. How can i told the compiler, dont search for `helloWorld()` in ClassA and use the function `helloWorld()` in ClassB?

```
//header of classa
class ClassA : public QDialog
{
 Q_OBJECT
 public:
    ClassA(QObject *parent = 0);
};

//header of classb
class ClassB : public ClassA
{
 public:
   ClassB();

 public slots:
    void helloWorld();
};

//cpp of classa
ClassA::ClassA(QObject *parent)
{
}

//cpp of classb
ClassB::ClassB()
{
QPushButton *btn = new QPushButton("Click");
connect(btn, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(helloWorld()));
QHBoxLayout *l = new QHBoxLayout();
l->addWidget(btn);
setLayout(l);
}

void ClassB::helloWorld()
{
   qDebug() << "hello world";
}
```

Comment: if you are creating the button and function in ClassB, why is the connect statement in ClassA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Angew answered.

The moc tool reads a C++ header file. If it finds one or more class declarations that contain the Q_OBJECT macro, it produces a C++ source file containing the meta-object code for those classes. Among other things, meta-object code is required for the signals and slots mechanism, the run-time type information, and the dynamic property system.

The C++ source file generated by moc must be compiled and linked with the implementation of the class.

More information here: http://woboq.com/blog/how-qt-signals-slots-work.html

Also you should test the return of the connect (true/false) and assert in case of failure. Avoid a lot of issues...

Answer (score 2):

`ClassB` is missing the `Q_OBJECT` macro; this means that from the point of view of Qt's metatype system, it is identical to `ClassA`. Adding `Q_OBJECT` to `ClassB` will solve the issue.

Comment: classb.cpp:7: undefined reference to `vtable for ClassB'

Comment: @user2372976 And line 7 happens to be...? BTW, did you re-run MOC on the `ClassB` header after adding `Q_OBJECT`?

Comment: line 7 is: `ClassB::ClassB()`, what is MOC? :D

Comment: @user2372976 `moc.exe`, Qt's meta-object compiler. It basically means you have to re-create your buildsystem after you add `Q_OBJECT` to a file where it wasn't used previously. If you're using `qmake`, that means re-running `qmake`.